# How many ways we can use to represent if else statement in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So far I can only find 3 ways.

First, `if-then-else`

Second, pattern matching

Third, using `|`. I don't know what this called.

Is there any other method to present *if else* statement in Haskell?

Comment: `|` is called a *guard*, btw

Comment: Perhaps the [`bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool) function counts (because of laziness)

Comment: `[e, t] !! fromEnum c`

Comment: [`extract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.3/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:extract)`(getMax (`[`Max`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Max)`(`[`Arg`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg)`False f) <> Max (Arg c t)))` @melpomene

Comment: `last$e:[t|c]` is a well known code golf spelling of if-then-else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Church-encoded Booleans](http://programmable.computer/posts/church_encoding.html):

```
Prelude> true = \t f -> t
Prelude> false = \t f -> f
Prelude> iff = id
Prelude> iff true "foo" "bar"
"foo"
Prelude> iff false 42 1337
1337
```

The `iff` function works like an `if..then..else` expression, enabling you to choose between two values, like `"foo"` and `"bar"`, or `42` and `1337`. Rooted in lambda calculus, this is essentially the foundation of logical branching. See the linked article for more details.

Not that I know why you'd do this, but you can...

Comment: This is also a handy illustration of `($) = id`.